# Can't figure out an "if/else" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax-error

PYTHON: Trying to calculate the period it takes for a pendulum to swing on different planets, I'm extremely new at this so there may be an easy solution:

```
def main():
    print('Period of a pendulum')
    Earth_gravity = 9.8
    Mars_gravity = 3.7263
    Jupiter_gravity = 23.12
    print('     ')
    pen = float(input('How long is the pendulum (m)? '))

if pen < 0:
    print('illegal length, length set to 1')
else:
    print('     ')
main()
```

What I want to do is if the value entered is negative for it to be set to "1" and display the message "illegal length, length set to 1" . If it is a positive number then I'll have it do the equation to find out the period of a pendulum swing. I am getting the syntax error message of " if pen < 0:
builtins.NameError: name 'pen' is not defined" Thank you!

Comment: put the statement after the main()

Comment: Your indentation is off. The `if` and `else` need to be indented like the rest of the function body.

Comment: @MauricioCortazar that won't help, `pen` is a local variable.

Comment: @AlexHall you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    print('Period of a pendulum')
    Earth_gravity = 9.8
    Mars_gravity = 3.7263
    Jupiter_gravity = 23.12
    print('     ')
    pen = float(input('How long is the pendulum (m)? '))
    if pen < 0:
        print('illegal length, length set to 1')
    else:
        print('     ')

main()
```

Try this: pen variable was outside the function therefore it was not accesible in if statement

Comment: Just check the tick if your query is solved and if you understood your mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You first define a method in which `pen` is defined:

```
def main():
    print('Period of a pendulum')
    Earth_gravity = 9.8
    Mars_gravity = 3.7263
    Jupiter_gravity = 23.12
    print('     ')
    pen = float(input('How long is the pendulum (m)? '))
```

But according to the indentation, you're now trying to use `pen` outside of `main` method:

```
if pen < 0:
    print('illegal length, length set to 1')
else:
    print('     ')
main()
```

You can move the `if/else` into `main` method or remove the `main` definition altogether.